# Changing the sizeof a video without altering the coordinates in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, video

I have written a code that runs a video frame by frame and performs different functions on it (detects events etc). I am struggling to resize the videos as they come in different sizes so they fit the screen - anything I have tried so far also changes the coordinates of the video - which is of no use since at the first frame I select an area of interest (with a bounding box) that I want to track. Any suggestions would be useful, code below:

```
def framebyframe(file_path):
   
    #A = Average of the BGR channel for the selected area of interest
    
    global fps
    framecount = 0
    framenumber = []
    B = []
    G = []
    R = []
    A = []
    
    if desiredvideo==1:
        root = tk.Tk()
        csv_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        root.withdraw()
        temp = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path, delimiter =',')                    
        Avfiltered = temp['Filtered signal'].tolist()
        roi = temp['ROI'].tolist()
        print(type(Avfiltered))
    else:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)
        
        width = int(cap.get(3))
        height = int(cap.get(4))
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
        out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 20.0, (width, height))

        if (cap.isOpened()== False):
            print("Error")
        
        fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, startframe)
        totalframenumber = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))  
        
        # runs the video until the last frame (totalframenumber-10) unless otherwise specified
        stopframe = 500
        print("Total frame number", totalframenumber)

        if (cap.isOpened() == True):
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret == True:
                
                #increase framecount with 1 after each frame
                framecount = framecount+1
                framenumber.append(framecount)
               
                if desiredvideo==0:
                    roi = cv2.selectROI(frame);
                else:
                    root = tk.Tk()
                    csv_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
                    root.withdraw()
                    temp = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path, delimiter =',')                    
                    roi = temp['ROI'].tolist()
                    
                frame_cropped = frame[int(roi[1]):int(roi[1]+roi[3]), int(roi[0]):int(roi[0] + roi[2]), :]
                

               
                tracker.init(frame, tuple(roi));
                backup.init(frame, tuple(roi));
               
                channelB, channelG,channelR = cv2.split(frame_cropped);
                B.append(np.mean(channelB))
                G.append(np.mean(channelG))
                R.append(np.mean(channelR))
                A.append((B[-1] + G[-1] + R[-1])/3)
       
        #while video is running for each frame update the tracker based on the area of interest
        while (cap.isOpened()):
           
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret == True:
                ret, roi = tracker.update(frame);
            else:
                print("Buffering on frame:", framenumber[-1])
           
            if ret == True:
                framecount = framecount+1
                framenumber.append(framecount)

    
                #get center of roi and use it create an inner frame with size 50x50
                roi = list(roi)
                if roi[1]<0:
                   roi[1] = 1
                frame_cropped = frame[int(roi[1]):int(roi[1]+roi[3]), int(roi[0]):int(roi[0] + roi[2]), :]
                c1 = int(roi[3]/2)
                c2 = int(roi[2]/2)
               
                # adjust inner frame size
                if c1 < ROIsize:
                    c1 = ROIsize
                   
                if c2 < ROIsize:
                    c2 = ROIsize
                   
                frame_inner = frame_cropped[c1 - ROIsize:c1+ROIsize, c2 - ROIsize:c2+ROIsize, :]
               
                # take channel averages for the inner frame
             
               
                channelB,channelG,channelR = cv2.split(frame_inner)
                B.append(np.mean(channelB))
                G.append(np.mean(channelG))
                R.append(np.mean(channelR))
               
               
                A.append((B[-1] + G[-1] + R[-1])/3)
               
                frame_cropped = cv2.circle(frame_cropped,(c2,c1), 10, (0,0,255), -1)
    
               
                frame_cropped = cv2.putText(frame_cropped, "Frame number: " + str(framecount), org, font, fontScale,
                        font_color, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA);
                

                cv2.imshow('Frame', frame_cropped)
                cv2.imshow('Inner frame', frame_inner)
    
               
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('Q'):
                    break
               
                if stopframe > 0:
                    if framenumber[-1] >= stopframe:
                        break

        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return A, framenumber, roi
```

Comment: again please, with a few examples, and less code, because most of that (132 lines total) appears irrelevant to the question. what exactly is the issue? you know the sizes of your inputs. you know what ROI you're cropping. the rest is just elementary arithmetic

Comment: If I understand your question, it is not possible to resize an image (frame) and have your coordinates of things in the image stay the same. You can pad your frames on the bottom and right and keep coordinates. But cropping (other than from the left and top) or resizing will change coordinates.  If I misunderstand, please explain further.